# simplebar v1.1.9 not working on firefox with bootstrap tab

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, scroll

Im using scroll plugin simplebar.js. It works good in all browser but I have issue in Firefox. When I'm tried to combine with bootstap tab, simplebar cannot render width in new tab at Firefox. I'm using simplebar v1.1.9. Please is there any suggestion or alternative way to get how this work

```css
.box {
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/Grsmto/simplebar/v1.1.9/dist/simplebar.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p>Some content.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <div class="box" data-simplebar-direction="vertical">
        <h3>Menu 2</h3>
        <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
        <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
        <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
        <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
        <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
        <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
        <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
        <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
        <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
        <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
        <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
        <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
        <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
        <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
        <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
        <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
        <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
        <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
        <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
        <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <div class="box" data-simplebar-direction="vertical">
        <h3>Menu 1</h3>
        <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
        <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
        <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
        <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
        <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
        <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
        <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
        <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
        <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
        <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
        <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
        <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
        <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
        <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
        <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
        <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
        <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
        <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
        <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
        <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
        <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
        <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
        <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
        <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
        <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
        <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
        <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>





<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/Grsmto/simplebar/v1.1.9/dist/simplebar.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call **recalculate** on bootstrap shown.bs.tab event.

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    $('.box').simplebar('recalculate');
});
```

Check this [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/4cpojg08/1/) in Firefox.

Comment: I see, I'tried to use recalculate from documentation, it show but scroll doesnt works. I didn't notice we should add listener to trigger, thank you very much. Still curious why firefox run different